# Django template output txt file with newlines

Tags: python, django, heroku, character-encoding

I am using Django to create a txt file for download via web interface.  On my local machine (Windows) using the development server the generated txt file looks good, with newlines as expected.  However when I deploy to Heroku (linux) and download the txt file, there are no newlines.

From the shell on the remote Heroku server I ran "file my_template.txt" and the response was ASCII text.  I suspect it has something to do with encoding and/or line endings (CR or LF).

The template is basically this (the full version with some unnecessary detail is further below)

```
{% for obj in data %}{{obj.somefield}}|{{obj.another_field}}
{% endfor %}
```

Full version:

```
{% load metamap_filters %}{% load i18n getter_tags %}{% for obj in data %}{{ obj|getattribute:'id'|nice_display|metamap_safe }}|{{ obj|getattribute:'short_name'|nice_display|metamap_safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I get the remote Heroku server to generate the txt file with newlines?